# Total Sitting Arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 5 people sitting on 5 chairs arranged in a straight line, all facing north. Everyone gets up and can do only one of the following things at a time.

(i) Sit back again in their original chair.

(ii)Turn their chair 180◦ to face south and then sit on it.

(iii) Sit on the chair next to their original
chair.

How many sitting arrangements are possible?

I have a doubt in this question I think the answer is 35 but I still have doubts. So I request my teachers to clear my doubts.

It is a multiple choice question where options are a)35 b)70 c)56 d)89

Comment: To be clear, "original chair" is in reference to the very first chair they started with?  Or is it in reference to the chair they most recently were sitting in?  Could we begin with (12345) and have person 1 change chairs to the right and 2 to their left, making it now (21345) and then have person 1 change chairs to the right again and 3 to their left making it (23145)?  Or is the fact that position 3 is not next to the first chair person 1 started from rendering this invalid?

Comment: Another similar question, "*can only do one of the following things at a time*"  Does this imply that they can not change seats and then also turn their seats around since that would be doing two things?  Or can they perform multiple actions in sequence... with each occurring "one at a time" as in only after the first is completed you perform the second action...

Comment: As written, the question is susceptible to multifarious interpretations, you really need to give full clarifications to get a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each person can perform at most one action in total:

*Claim:* If some person $x$ were to change seats to a seat to their side, the person $y$ whose seat they took must then change seats to where $x$ came from.

Suppose otherwise.  If $y$ stayed still, you have two people in the same seat.  That presumably can't happen.  So then $y$ must be changing seats.  Supposing without loss of generality that both $x$ and $y$ moved to the right, then since no person can move further than one seat away you will have more seats than people on their left which again can not happen.

So, any and all seat exchanges must be between pairs of adjacent people.  In the event there was only one pair exchanging seats, choose which pair it was  (1,2),(2,3),(3,4) or (4,5).  Then for all remaining people, choose if they did or did not rotate their chair.  This gives $4\times 2^3$

In the event two seat exchanges took place, pick which adjacent pairs exchanged seats, it being ((1,2),(3,4)), ((1,2),(4,5)), or ((2,3),(4,5)).  Then for the remaining person, choose if they did or did not rotate their chair.  This gives $3\times 2$

Then finally there might be the case that no persons exchanged seats.  For such a scenario, we simply ask each if they did or did not rotate their chair for another $2^5$ possibilities

This gives a combined total of $2^5+4\times 2^3 + 6 = 70$

---

In the event people may perform multiple actions repeatedly, and may stray further than one space away from their original chair, it is well known that the set of adjacent transpositions generates the entirety of $S_n$ and so all arrangements of people in chairs is possible, and then all chairs may be turned or not, for a total of $5!\times 2^5=3840$.

In the event people may perform actions repeatedly, but may not stray further than one space away from their original chair, we get use similar analysis as before to get $(4+3)\times 2^5=224$

Comment: the correct answer is 70 but how? I hope you can do now

Comment: Your first interpretation leads to $70$ if you include the possibility that no pairs exchange seats, with $2^5$ possible orientations.

Comment: Can you please post how can we get 70 assuming the probability is real.

Comment: @joriki ah, of course.  Silly me.

Comment: @TechnoHighway corrected, I had somehow forgotten the case of no seat exchanges.  It is indeed 70.

Comment: @joriki where is your solution?

Comment: @JMoravitz can you describe your solution a bit? I am not able to clearly understand this and if you won't mind I would like to ask you a similar permutation and combination question:

How many permutations of the first 9 positive integers satisfy both properties? 
 The leftmost even number is 6.
 The rightmost odd number is 9.

Comment: @TechnoHighway: I don't have a different solution. I just pointed out an oversight in this solution that’s now been corrected.

Comment: @joriki Oh! Thanks for your time. Can you give me your solution to this problem:

How many permutations of the first 9 positive integers satisfy both properties? 
 The leftmost even number is 6.
 The rightmost odd number is 9.

Comment: @TechnoHighway With regards to the new question, you should ask it in a new post... not in the comments of another unrelated question.  With regards to the current question, what specifically are you not following?

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you give me your email address so that I can clear my doubts there?

Comment: @JMoravitz With regards to first question can you point out the ways of each arrangement seperately like sit back in original chair, turn 180 degree and sit next to each other.

Comment: It can be done [in the chatroom here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151498/combinatorics-for-techno), no need for email.

Comment: @TechnoHighway: I agree that's not sufficiently related and should be asked in a new post. Feel free to ping me here when you’ve posted the question and I’ll take a look at it.

Comment: @joriki Can You invite to a chatroom so that we can talk about some problems?

Comment: @TechnoHighway: No, I have a very tight schedule these days, I can't spend time in chats.

Comment: @joriki I have posted another question from my 2nd id please answer it if you can 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863341/finding-the-value-of-functions