# Finding the value of functions:

Tags: functions, summation

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $g(f(x + y)) = f(x) + (x+y)g(y)$.
The value of $(0) + (1)+. . . (2024)$ is?

My attempt:
When x=0 and y=0 then, g(f(0))=f(0)..........(i).

When x=0 and y=1 then, g(f(1))=f(0)+g(1)

or, g(f(1))   =g(f(0))+g(1) [because f(0)=g(f(0)) from equation (i)]

Similarly,

g(f(2))=g(f(0))+2g(2)

I did this question upto this and didn't get any hint to proceed further. I hope someone helps me. One can solve this in his/her own way and if possible continue my way.

Since, this is a multiple choice question, the options are

(a)0
(b)$\frac{(2024)(2024+1)}{2}$

(c)$\frac{(2024)(2024-1)}{2}$
(d) 2025

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Oh thanks I'll follow it from now on

Comment: @joriki Can you solve it?

Comment: There’s an edit button; you can fix this post.

Comment: Hey! I did it I hope you will post the solutions now!

Comment: I don’t know the solution to this. There’s no connection between bringing the question in line with the conventions of this site and me posting a solution to it. (By the way, most of the question is still not properly typeset.)

Comment: @MissionJoshi: I've started introducing MathJax to your question in order to improve readability.

Comment: Start by putting $y=-x$. This is an easy question and the answer is  (a).

Comment: When I used y=-x, I got g(f(0))=f(x)

what can I do next?