# $g(f(x + y)) = f(x) + (x+y)g(y).$ Value of $(0) + (1)+\dots+ (2024)$?

Tags: functions, summation, real-numbers

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that for all real numbers $x$ and $y$:

$$g(f(x + y)) = f(x) + (x+y)g(y).$$

The value of $(0) + (1)+\ldots (2024)$ is?

I found the question on Mathematics Stack Exchange:

[Finding the value of functions:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863341/finding-the-value-of-functions?noredirect=1#comment10369148_4863341)

As the question was unanswered, I tried to solve it but couldn't get to the answer. I tried the approach of the questioner in the mentioned post but didn't find it any useful.

Edit:

My Approach:

According to the suggestion provided, when I use $y=-x$ in the original equation:

$$g(f(0))=f(x)$$

This implies that $f(x)$ is constant for every inputs i.e. $f(0)=g(f(0))$, $f(1)=g(f(0))$, $f(2)=g(f(0))$, etc.

But how does it imply that $g$ is identically equal to $0$; i.e. $g≡0$

I have thought of the following to prove $g≡0$ and I don't know whether it is right or wrong. Please point out my mistake or continue in your own way.

When we replace the value of $f(x)=g(f(0))$ in the original equation, we get,

$$g(g(f(0))=g(f(0))+(x+y)g(y)$$

Since $g(g(f(0))$, $g(f(0))$ and $(x+y)$ are all constants, we can write that $g(y)$ is also a constant for every values of $y$.

After this, I'm lost in the way. I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: $y=-x$ gives $g(f(0))=f(x)$ so $f$ is a  constant. This forces $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: I am not able to understand , post it as a solution please! Or suggest ways clearly.

Comment: Can you explain how does it force g to be congruent to 0.

Comment: I think he means "identically equal," not congruent.

Comment: You have to make some attempt.  There are plenty of hints already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g(f(x+y))=f(x)+(x+y)g(y)$$

Let $y=-x$

$$g(f(0))=f(x)$$

Now in original substitute $x=0$ and $x=1$ to get

$$
g(f(y))=f(0)+yg(y)\\g(f(y+1))=f(1)+(y+1)g(y)
$$

Subtract both to get
$$
g(f(y+1))-g(f(y))=f(1)-f(0)+g(y)
$$

Since $f(x)=g(f(0))$ we get

$$
g(g(f(0)))-g(g(f(0)))=g(f(0))-g(f(0))+g(y)\\
g(y)=0
$$